# Touched Project Structure now the project cannot find any packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I just ruined my android project.  I touched the Project structure added a dependency (for gdx-tools). There weren't any dependencies before. Now Gradle cannot find find any libraries.

```
Error:(32, 0) Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android:natives'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':core'.
> Could not open buildscript class cache for build file '..\build.gradle' (..\.gradle\caches\1.11\scripts\build_5nf261mprglcnmchu7kvpoddt6\ProjectScript\buildscript).
> Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file '..\core\build.gradle' (..\.gradle\caches\1.11\scripts\build_5nf261mprglcnmchu7kvpoddt6\ProjectScript\buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 3732
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: ..\.gradle\caches\1.11\scripts\build_5nf261mprglcnmchu7kvpoddt6\ProjectScript\buildscript\cache.properties.lock
```

Anyone knows how to fix this, without generating a new project?

Answer (score 3):

Exit Android Studio, clear out the Gradle cache folder whose path is in the error message, and relaunch.

Comment: Found something, when I add com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:0.9.9@jar manually to the dependencies, it will work again, but I haven't seen it before here... Does gradle have it's own configuration for dependencies?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cache which gradle maintain for all the dependancies which we add in build.gradle file in user's directory.

In Windows:

> C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches

In Mac:

> /Users/UserName/.gradle/caches

**Delete the caches folder.** Now next time when you run gradle sysc then it will download all dependencies again and the problem of lock should be resolved.

This problem is also reported as an issue: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795

Answer (score 0):

This lock issue happened to me when I was running 
`gradle run`
in another bash window.

I just had to stop that to get it working again.